# JQuery table select closest empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select a class which is from the same table (and row).
If the user clicks on "Remove", I need to grab the text from "form_delete_id".
Unfortunately I get an empty string back. I tried "closest()" and "parent()" without luck.
This is my code:

```
<table class="responsive-table bordered striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>page</th>
      <th>parameter</th>
      <th>method</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="form_delete_id">2</td>
      <td class="form_delete_page">dqfsq</td>
      <td class="form_delete_parameter">qsdfqs</td>
      <td class="form_delete_method">post</td>
      <td class="form_delete_trigger"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn red"><i class="material-icons left">delete</i>Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And the Javascript below it:

```
<script>
$(".form_delete_trigger").click(function() {
  alert($(this).closest(".form_delete_id").text());
});
</script>
```

My code can also be found on [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/39cbacf4/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.form_delete_id` is sibling element of clicked `.form_delete_id` .You need to use `.siblings()` instead of `.closest()`:

```js
$(function(){
 $(".form_delete_trigger").click(function() {
  alert($(this).siblings(".form_delete_id").text());
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="responsive-table bordered striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>page</th>
      <th>parameter</th>
      <th>method</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="form_delete_id">2</td>
      <td class="form_delete_page">dqfsq</td>
      <td class="form_delete_parameter">qsdfqs</td>
      <td class="form_delete_method">post</td>
      <td class="form_delete_trigger"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn red"><i class="material-icons left">delete</i>Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer! I didn't knew that [siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) should be used when lists and tables are used. Thanks for introducing this feature to me.

Comment: @yoano: glad it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the parent and searching it for the delete id:

```
<script>
$(".form_delete_trigger").click(function() {
  alert($(this).parent().find(".form_delete_id").text());
});
</script>
```

or using sibiling

```
<script>
$(".form_delete_trigger").click(function() {
  alert($(this).siblings(".form_delete_id").text());
});
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t8okf8kc/